# matplotlib FuncAnimation: when to stop?

Tags: python, matplotlib

According to matplotlib's documentation, `FuncAnimation` calls a funtion repeatedly to make an animation.

The question is, how should I tell `FuncAnimation()` to stop when no more image data available?

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many frames are in your image data then make sure among the other arguments in `FuncAnimation()` that you have:

```
frames=#frames
repeat=False
```

It then stops when it reaches the frame limit. 
Not perfect but this seems to be a common concern without a proper solution.

Comment: How about when I only know when the frames end from within the update function?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html

> FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=None, init_func=None, fargs=None, save_count=None, **kwargs)
>
> "...Frames can be a generator, an iterable, or a number of frames..."

If you are passing frames one at a time, an iterable will run out, and the animation will stop.

Comment: @Manheim, thx, it works when frames data are ready before FuncAnimation() is called. But what if image data can only be retrieved in 'func'?

Comment: I'm unsure of exactly how your code works, but I suspect that you want to refactor something in order to get this to work.